# Rewrite Rules en archivos htaccess

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Tengo un archivo htaccess de un framework de PHP, como este

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?1 [L,QSA]
```

Con eso mando todos los request al controlador de rutas y todo va bien, si no hay clases que manejen la solicitud, se envia a un 404 preparado en el ruteador y evito el acceso a los archivos porque los modulos estan una carpeta publica.

En una ocasion me fije que se puede agregar un RewriteEngine off en un .htaccess dentro de un subfolder y asi evitar el redireccionamiento de los folders protegidos del sistema, hay alguna manera de evitar esto? de que se coloque de manera arbitraria un .htaccess en subfolder y bloquear el redireccionamiento al controlador principal?

Comment: Mira lo que dicen en [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737525/how-can-i-make-htaccess-files-in-a-subfolder-not-execute).  Resumen: Solo lo conseguirias poniendo las rules en el apache, no usando ningun .htaccess y estableciendo la directiva `AllowOverride None`, pero para ello tienes que tener acceso a los archivos de configuración de apache.

Comment: Como seria para un shared webhosting donde no se tiene acceso a los archivos de config de apache? Creo que no seria posible

Comment: En un hosting compartido no te lo permitiran porque son archivos que pueden afectar a todos y no solo a tu cuenta.  Si lo que quieres es controlar que no te metan malware en forma de .htaccess en subdirectorios podrias crear un cron que se ejecute cada minuto (es lo mínimo que permite el cron) muy simple, con un `find` desde la raiz pública que te mande un aviso por mail conforme ha encontrado uno y lo renombre para su analisis posterior o lo borre directamente.  No es lo mismo, pero es una protección más.  Por ejemplo lo puedes hacer en bash o php.